# React Native/Shoutem: navigateBack() not working

Tags: react-native, shoutem, react-native-navigation

My Problem is that I would like to navigateBack() from the BountyDetailsScreen to the LoyaltyScreen, but the navigateBack() function call does not trigger any action. When I log the function it says:

[image]

The only thing I notice is, that the navigationStack is empty. When I do the same with the `navigateTo` function it is working, but then I have a messed up navigation stack.

In my LoyaltyScreen.js I am displaying a ListView. It is a RN ListView (not imported from shoutem).

**LoyaltyScreen.js**

```
renderRow(bounty) {
  return (
    <ListBountiesView
      key={bounty.id}
      bounty={bounty}
      onDetailPress={this.openDetailsScreen}
      redeemBounty={this.redeemBounty}
    />
  );
}
```

**ListBountiesView.js**

The ListBountiesView renders each ListView Row and opens a Detail Screen when clicked on the Row.

```
render() {
const { bounty } = this.props;

return (      
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onDetailPress}>          
    {bounty.type == 0 ? this.renderInShopBounty() : this.renderContestBounty()}
    <Divider styleName="line" />
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
}
```

**BountyDetailsScreen.js**

In the BountyDetailsScreen I display detailed information and would like to navigateBack() to the Loyalty Screen when I press a button.

```
<Button styleName="full-width" onPress={() => this.onRedeemClick()}>
  <Icon name="add-to-cart" />
  <Text>Einlösen</Text>
</Button>

onRedeemClick() {
  const { bounty, onRedeemPress } = this.props;
  onRedeemPress(bounty);
  navigateBack();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*navigateBack* is an action creator. You need to map it to props and read it from props in your *redeemClick* function. Just executing the imported action creator won't do anything since it's not connected to Redux.

Here's an example of you map it to props:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { navigateBack })(SomeScreen));
```

Here's how you use it:

```
const { navigateBack } = this.props;

navigateBack();
```

Comment: Thanks you! I forgot to read the `navigateBack()` function from props

Answer (score 1):

I can see that airmiha's answer is what you're looking for, but I just wanted to add onto it.

You can also use hasHistory to set up your [@shoutem/ui](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/introduction) [NavigationBar](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/navigation-bar) (if you're using it) with a simple back button that utilises navigateBack().

```
<NavigationBar
  styleName="no-border"
  hasHistory
  title="The Orange Tabbies"
  share={{
    link: 'http://the-orange-tabbies.org',
    text: 'I was underwhelmed by The Orange Tabbies, but then I looked at that 
          sweet, sweet back button on the Nav Bar. 
          #MakeNavBarsGreatAgain',
    title: 'Nevermind the cats, check the Nav Bar!',
  }}
/>
```

You can find more examples with the NavigationBar component [here](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/navigation-bar).